# URL redirection with multiple files

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule account$ account.php [Nc]
RewriteRule (.+)$ store.php [Nc]
```

When I visit `http://localhost/project/account` it should be redirected to `account.php`

If I visit `http://localhost/project/sun-glass` it should be redirected on `store.php`

Comment: And what is the "problem"? Do you get an error with what you have tried? Or not the desired result? What exactly happens?

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file created? Inside `localhost/project/`?

Comment: Both URL are redirect on same file (store.php). Yes my .htaccess file inside.